# Maas deployment failes while commissioning works

Tags: networking, maas, openstack

I installed MAAS in our testing environment to try out OpenStack Autopilot.
Everything worked fine but when I try to deploy a node it ends up in "deployment failed - timeout after 40min".
When I take a look in the "commissioning output" I see that there is a DNS issue: "sudo: unable to resolve host Juju-Controller: Connection timed out".

The strange thing on that is that DNS resolution works fine on a commissioned host which I stopped from shutting down.

Any ideas?